# How to change all non word characters and multiple spaces into ' ' and then all space to '-' in one preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to change image names on below conditions

- All non word characters turns into space  and
- then all spaces turns into `-`

means  if my image name  is : `Hello       My name is'Kh@n "Mr. .Khan "` then it should be changed into `Hello-My-name-is-kh-n-mr-Khan`  .

i need to use below in two steps,

```
$old_name ='       Hello       My name is\'Kh@n "Mr. Khan        ';
$space_name = preg_replace('/\W/',' ', $old_name);
$new_name= preg_replace('/\s+/','-', $space_name);

echo $new_name // returns Hello-My-name-is-kh-n-mr-Khan
```

is there any way to apply both conditions in single step??

Comment: Why do it in a single step? It's much, much simpler to just do it in two steps, and it doesn't really gain you anything to combine it.

Comment: So it's okay to do in two steps...Thank You Amber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this function's output (`Hello_My_name_is-Kh-n_-Mr-_Khan_`)a bit ugly
Here is my approach

```
$name ='Hello       My name is\'Kh@n "Mr. Khan" ';
$name = preg_replace('/\W/',' ', $name);
$name = trim($name);
$name = strtolower($name);
$name = preg_replace('/\s+/','-', $name);
```

outputs 
`hello-my-name-is-kh-n-mr-khan`

Comment: Sharpnel...Thanks for your great idea, how do we limit the length of name ( only 200 )

Comment: @JustLearn you can add substr() function call as well.

Comment: start to replace `\W+` with a dash and trim the dashes. This way you don't need a second replacement. Eventually change `\W` to `[\W_]`

Answer (score 6):

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) can take arrays:

```
$new_name = preg_replace(array('/\s+/', '/\W/'), array('_', '-'), $old_name);
```

This is more succinct, but I don't believe it's any more efficient. The docs don't specify an order that the regexps are applied. Since space characters are non-word characters, a safer version is:

```
$new_name = preg_replace(array('/\s+/', '/[^\s\w]/'), array('_', '-'), $old_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays in `preg_replace`:

```
$old_name ='Hello       My name is\'Kh@n "Mr. Khan ';
$new_name = preg_replace(array('/\s+/','/\W/'),array('_','-'),$old_name);
```

Also,

Your snippet has syntax error, you need to escape the single quote before `K`

Answer (score 0):

Is this to rename uploaded images? If so, keep in mind...

- max char count (should snip it at something sensible)
- non ASCII chars? (transliterate would be best)

Comment: what i needs o take care more??